# Webcam settings are reset by each app

Tags: webcam, v4l

I have Razer Kiyo Pro web camera on Ubuntu 20.04 and configure it via

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --set-fmt-video=width=640,height=480,pixelformat=H264
```

and then check via

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --all
```

that the settings are applied.

However, when I start an app that is using web camera, like Zoom or VLC, it discards all the settings I've set and replaces them with its own resolution and format. How do I avoid such behavior and make the apps use my settings?